# Generating random numbers in SAS

Tags: sas

how to generate random integers between 10 and 50 using ranuni() function in sas.

For generating random integer between 1 to 5, I used this code

```
data random;
 do i=1 to 10;
    random_int = int(ranuni(0) * 5 + 1);
    output;
 end;
```

run;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the same logic, you could use:

```
random_int = int(ranuni(0) * 41 + 10);
```

`ranuni` returns a value from interval `<0, 1>`, multiply it by 41 and you get a value from `<0, 41>`, add 10 and the final value is from `<10, 51>`. Casting to int just cuts off the decimal part so you will never get 51.

Generaly:

```
a * ranuni(seed) + b;
```

returns a value from interval `<b, a + b>`.

Answer (score 1):

If u is a random uniform variate in [0,1], then x = a + (b-a)*u is random uniform on [a,b].
See http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/08/24/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-sas/